# Bootstrap Affix not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I try to use **Bootstrap affix** to make an element, during `affix` on bottom of page and on `affix-top` to top od the page.

I implement affix and on desktop it works like a charm but on mobile it doesn't work. I mean: on mobile there aren't the toggle of the classes and it remain always with `affix-top` class..

I use this code:

```
    <div class="affix-div" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
```

and css are:

```
.affix-div.affix {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Why on mobile not change the classes??

(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap affix calculates offset based on document height, window scrollTop and the element's offset. One of the pitfall here is the $(window).scrollTop. According to the [overflow specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-overflow-3/#overflow-properties), if you set the body's overflow property neither to `visible` or `clip` values, it makes the body a scroll container and scrollTop wont work anymore, because now the body is a scroll container and scrolling takes effect inside of it, not in the window.

Look for the body `overflow`, `overflow-x` or `overflow-y` properties and set the values to `visible`. If you need the overflowing effect, just wrap the body's content inside of a another element and set the overflow there.